# .Net Framework 4.5 AddObject() does not appear

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a class that I want to make `Insert`, `Update`, `Delete` operations in it.

```
// Constructor.
public BaseManager()
{
    // Disable lazy loading.
    this.Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}

public DBEntities Context = new DBEntities();
```

In this class, I can't use `AddObject()` extension method on `Context` variable. `AddObject()` method does not appear typing after `Context.`

Here are my imported namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

I was able to use it in .Net Framework 3.5 but not working on .Net Framework 4.5

What I've doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Importing `using System.Data.Entity;` or `using System.Data.Objects;` not working.

Here is the method I want to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx

**UPDATE AGAIN:**

I realized that my DBEntities derives from `DbContext` in .Net Framework 4.5 but it was deriving from `ObjectContext` in .Net Framework 3.5, so I was able to use `AddObject()` method.

Original entities class:

```
public partial class DBEntities : DbContext
    {
        // ...
    }
```

I want to do like this:

```
public partial class DBEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        // ...
    }
```

If I change base class from `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` does it constitute any problem?

Comment: I think you need `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: I've had already tried that but doesn't work.

Comment: maybe: `using System.Data.Objects;`

Comment: Nope, I've had also tried that already.

Comment: Have you tried `Context.YourEntity.Add(new YourNewEntityDataModel)`?

Comment: Context is my entity class. So there is no such extension method like Context.MyEntity

Comment: Your context would contain properties for your entities. Can you show us bit more of how your context(DBEntities) class is defined?

Comment: It is edmx file generated from my database.

Comment: That's right, it should have backing properties for each table in your database.

Comment: Maybe you have to step back and think about this DbContext API. It's there for a reason. If you build your application logic around it, it will guide you to better patterns than the ObjectContext API. Dealing with untyped objects usually is a very bad pattern that requires boxing and unboxing and numerous type checks, leading to bloated and clunky code. If I were you I would not return to the old API but bite the bullet and rework your architecture.

Answer (score 9):

Expand `YourModel.edmx` file. you can see 4 files there.Delete the files with `.tt extension.`. Then double click on `YourModel.edmx` file. In `YourModel.edmx` diagram window right click and chose `Properties.`

In the properties window set Code Generation Strategy **None** to **Default**.

[image: Screenshot]

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

`AddObject` exists on each entity inside your container.

```
Context.TableName.AddObject(New TableElement...)
```

Comment: It's not what I want to achieve. I don't want to specify table name at there. Here is the method I want to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx

Comment: Then add the namespace `sa_ddam` mentioned.